# ExtJS7: Routes with query parameters not matching

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6, sencha-cmd, extjs7

I have implemented routes to match query parameters in ExtJS7 with following routes code

```
        ':node:params': {
          before: 'isLoggedIn',
          action: 'onAction',
          conditions: {
            ':params': '(^\\?[%a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\_\\s,&=]+)'
          }
        }
```

I have also tried with following code

```
        ':node?:params': {
          before: 'isLoggedIn',
          action: 'onAction'
        }
```

in both cases, routes with query parameters are not being matched to above routes but invokes `unmatchedroute` action

Comment: What does your url look like?  it has a Hash correct?

Comment: yes. It does contain a hash i.e #catalog?a=b

Answer (score 1):

You can't match routes to query parameters. The Router matches based on the `window.location.hash` - the part of the URL after the `#`. Query parameters are part of the `window.location.querystring`; there is no overlap.

You *can* [parameterise routes](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.0/guides/application_architecture/router.html#application_architecture-_-router_-_hashes_with_parameters) - but not with query parameters.

Comment: that meaning `action/:id` should match both `#action/123` and `#action/123?a=b`. But actually ExtJs treats both differently. It only matches `#action/123` correctly and raises `unmatchedroute` for `#action/123?a=b`

Comment: The body of a URL is <protocol>://<host>/<path>?<queryparams>#<hash>.

So for a normal URL, the query params would be `?a=b#action/123.

Comment: For the Router, parts of the route must be separated by /. So `action/:node/:params` would work to match, say, `#action/123/a=b`, with `node` being 123 and `params` being a=b. But you can't easily use ? as the separator.

Comment: If you _have_ to use that form, then simply match `action/:node_and_params`, and then split `node_and_params` on the ? in your route handler.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm 3 years late here, but it is possible to use "?" as your 'params' identifier for the extjs router, so you can have the router match #action/123 and #action/123?a=b, you just need the right regex for your conditions. I use something similar to this:

```
'action:params': {
      before: 'isLoggedIn',
      action: 'onAction',
      conditions: {
        ':params': '(?:(?:\\\??){1}([%=&a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\_\\s,&=]+))?'
      }
}
```

Wrapping the input with a non-capturing group with the "?" quantifier at the end allows navigation to #action with no following query. You also need to escape both the backslash and the "?" in the inner non-capturing group as "\?" so the regex is correctly parsed as "?".

The only potentially odd interaction I've found with this is that if the router receives just "#my-view?" with no following query string, the onAction method is passed "?" for 'params' but that's easy enough to account for.